# Making a pattern transparent in illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I am new to illustrator and really need some help;) I AM NOT ASKING FOR YOU TO DO THE WORK FOR ME I JUST NEED ADVICE. I have filled the mustang with a black and white pattern, I need to make the black transparent. I would list what I've tried but once again, I'm new, so I haven't tried anything.

Comment: The pattern is black and white and i need it to be white and transparent. I need to black part of the pattern transparent

Comment: It's still off topic because we require what you've tried.  If you make an [edit] with what you've tried and where you're having issues we can reopen it to assist you.  If you're asking for someone to do it for you that is not what the site is about and you should take the [tour]

Comment: I'm not asking for somehow to do it, I'm asking HOW to do it. You aren't making any sense, this isn't showing what I've tried, this is just showing the mustang with the pattern.

Comment: Also, what I want to point out is that you asked the first question on how to cut the mustang here : http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/66576/deleting-part-of-a-traced-item-in-adobe-illustrator and two people answered but you didn't give any feedback on the answeres even thou it apparently helped you.

Comment: Ya we arent a service board to do your work.  The site purpose is to answer questions that in fact can be answered and providing a tutorial isnt in the scope of this site.  You're asking for a tutorial with no shown effort.  If you make an [edit] to show us what you've tried and why you cant do it we will be happy to repoen this question and assist you.  However we arent going to do your work for you and that is why i closed your last question.

Comment: you say "we" as if you own the website. Once again, I'm not asking for you to do the work for me. I am new to illustrator and just need some advice in which I'll find somewhere else because you are very rude. If the question wasn't relevant, it wouldn't have let me post in the first place.

Comment: Also, I didn't list what I have tried because I don't know what to try. That is why I found myself at this "friendly" website in the first place, trying to seek help.

Comment: We, as in the community.  I'm not being rude Im trying to nicely explain to you what the site is about.  Granted the SE model is different then typical sites and takes some getting used that is why I encouraged you to take the [tour].  You may be new to Illustrator but as you say that I am being rude I would like you to consider that you're asking for people to spend their time to show you how to do something when you wont spend the time yourself to let us know where you're having problems.  The system lets anyone ask a question and its up to the community to vote and decide if it's in scope.

Comment: Based on your [edit] I do not mind helping point you into the right direction searching our site, [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator+pathfinder) is where you could start.

Comment: I didn't spend my time showing y'all my problems? lol ok. Anyways, you still didn't have to close my question.

Comment: All i see is you spent the time asking for help.  Ive even assisted pointing you in the right direction yet all you appear to do is argue.  I did have to close your question because your question isnt in scope.  Ive tried to show you that and all you want to do is argue so yhis question will now be locked.